# Twitter bootstrap highlight buttons on hover

Tags: button, twitter-bootstrap, less, styling

The default Twitter Bootstrap 2 button styling makes the buttons darker on hover. As far as I can see, this is done by having a light, gradient overlay on buttons and make this overlay move to -15px on hover, which make the button darker.

I would like to know, if I can make a general change that makes the button lighter on hover, say the opposite experience as the default?

**NOTE:** Switching `@btnBackgroundHighlight` and `@btnBackground` in `variables.less` (I use less for bootstrap) ends up making buttons lighter on the lower part than the upper part (when not hovering). This gives a feeling that the button is somehow pressed/disabled. I would like the upper part of the button to be ligthest at all times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default button have a gradient from @btnBackground (top) to (@btnBackgroundHighlight) and set the hover color to @btnBackgroundHighlight. Switch the colors won't help cause a light hover will always have the gradient from dark to light and visa versa.

**Solution 1**:

Generate a button on: http://twitterbootstrapbuttons.w3masters.nl/ choose the first light variant. Switch the gradient color of the code by hand. Don't forget to hover overlay to in your css by adding: `background-position: 0 15px;`

**Solution 2**:

Generate your code with less by adding:

```
.buttonBackgroundReverse(@startColor, @endColor, @textColor: #fff, @textShadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.25)) {
  // gradientBar will set the background to a pleasing blend of these, to support IE<=9
  .gradientBar(@startColor, @endColor, @textColor, @textShadow);
  *background-color: @endColor; /* Darken IE7 buttons by default so they stand out more given they won't have borders */
  .reset-filter();

  // in these cases the gradient won't cover the background, so we override
  &:hover, &:focus, &:active, &.active, &.disabled, &[disabled] {
    color: @textColor;
    background-color: @startColor;
    *background-color: darken(@startColor, 5%);
  }
  &:hover, &:focus {background-position: 0 15px;}

  // IE 7 + 8 can't handle box-shadow to show active, so we darken a bit ourselves
  &:active,
  &.active {
    background-color: darken(@startColor, 10%) e("\9");
  }
}

@darkcolor: #46a546;
@lightcolor : lighten(#46a546, 30%);
.btn-light 
{
.buttonBackgroundReverse(@lightcolor,@darkcolor);
}
```

Use @darkcolor to set your button color also change the percentage of @lightcolor to your needs. See http://bootply.com/65731 for an example.